# Seaborn/Matplotlib: Scatter plot with hue colours (like a heat map) for different variables in legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am very new to Matplotlib and python in general, and want to show a scatter plot with a colour map e.g. hot which corresponds to the legend.

My data is set up as two lists of lists (`x_list` and `y_list`), with lengths of 100 each.

```
for i in x_list:
   x_list[i] = # list of data corresponding to a function where T = i
```

I have a plot like this, where each colour is a value of T:

```
for T in range(100):
    x = x_list[T]
    y = y_list[T]
    
    plt.scatter(x, y, label="T{}".format(T))
```

[image]

Ideally I want it to look like this from the seaborn module, like so

[image]

Where the colour assigned to each point is a colour map gradient according to what the value of T is.

Can I do this with the colourmap cm in Matplotlib?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an rgb color array and pass as parameter to matplotlib's scatter function

```
colors = [(t/100,0,0) for t in range(len(x_list))] 
plt.scatter(x_list, y_list, color=colors)
```